# Django: How to attach a file without referencing a file destination?

Tags: django, email, django-forms, django-views, attachment

I am looking to attach a file to an email which includes all the content a user inputs from a contact form. I currently refer a PDF which records their inputs, and I attach that PDF from a file destination. However, I do not know how to attach additional files which the user provides on the contact form. In this case, this is represented by "msg.attach_file(upload_file)." My thoughts are:

1. Have the file be uploaded to a destination; however, it needs to renamed to a uniform name each time so I can refer to it during the attachment process (msg.attach_file).
2. Figure out a way to use request.FILES to attach it immediately without having to worry about its file name or upload destination (I am not sure if msg.attach_file is a valid command for this method).

Is there a right way to perform this action? I am attempting to perform **method 2** with my **views.py** file which refers to my forms.py file, but it is giving me an error.

**Views.py**

```
def quote_req(request):
submitted = False
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = QuoteForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    company = request.POST['company']
    contact_person = request.POST['contact_person']
    upload_file = request.FILES['upload_file']
    description = 'You have received a sales contact form'
    if form.is_valid():
        data_dict = {
            'company_': str(company),
            'contact_person_': str(contact_person),
            }
        write_fillable_pdf(INVOICE_TEMPLATE_PATH, INVOICE_OUTPUT_PATH, data_dict)
        form.save()
        # assert false
        msg = EmailMessage('Contact Form', description, settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, ['sample@mail.com'])
        msg.attach_file('/uploads/file.pdf')
        msg.attach_file(upload_file)
        msg.send(fail_silently=False)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/quote/?submitted=True')
else:
    form = QuoteForm()
    if 'submitted' in request.GET:
        submitted = True
```

---

**Error Log**

```
TypeError at /quote/

expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not InMemoryUploadedFile

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://www.mytestingwebsitesample.com/quote/
Django Version:     2.1.3
Exception Type:     TypeError
Exception Value:    

expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not InMemoryUploadedFile
```

Comment: you didn't show your `QuoteForm` but if you're saving the file in the `Quote` model (with `form.save()`) you can also do: `quote = form.save(); msg.attach_file(quote.file.path)`. (I don't know your model, so I''m just assuming a `file` field).

Comment: This is the method I am thinking of going with. Is there a way I can rename the file to a singular name each time a form is submitted (effectively replacing the last uploaded file)?

Comment: you want to re-use the same `quote` object? ie. you don't really care about keeping the various objects in the db? Then initialise your `QuoteForm` with the existing instance (`QuoteForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=existing_quote)` where you first fetch the existing quote). That way the saved file is replaced each time.

Comment: I do not mind if the upload is replaced; however, I need it to be an exact file name so I can reference it during attachment. Will using an instance accomplish this (something like os.rename)?

Comment: I don’t understand “exact file name “ and “reference during attachment”. As I said, `quote.file.path` is the full path to the file (including its file name) so why do you care what the specific file name is?

Comment: My apologies if unclear. In my models.py I have "upload_assay = models.FileField(upload_to='/uploads/', blank=True)," so when the user attaches their file and sends the contact form, it drops into that folder. When I have the form and its document attachments sub-sequentially emailed to an employee, I must reference the exact location (with file name) in order to attach it to the email command. I am currently having the issue where I have a randomly named file from a user and I need it renamed something else in order to email it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following? Since `InMemoryUploadedFile` doesn't work, might have to process it first

```
upload_file = request.FILES['upload_file']
content = upload_file.read()
attachment = (upload_file.name, content, 'application/pdf')
# . . . 
msg.attach(attachment)
```

Comment: I still receive the TypeError "expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not InMemoryUploadedFile" for the content line. I believe it is referring to the upload_file not being a string?

Comment: I receive the error message "No exception message supplied" after implementing the updated lines @ .virtualenvs/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py in attach

Answer (score 0):

`upload_file.read()` will return bytes. You might want to try using `attach` instead of `attach_file`. `attach_file` requires the file to be saved to your filesystem, while attach can take data. However, I believe that with `attach`, you should be able to use `request.FILES['upload_file']` directly.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/email/#emailmessage-objects

Comment: Is there a certain way to accomplish this beyond using "msg.attach(upload_file)?" Currently I receive an exception error with my current syntax.

Comment: What's the exception you're getting? Just using `msg.attach(upload_file)` won't work because attach takes 3 arguments - example from the docs `message.attach('whatyouwanttonamethefile.pdf', upload_file, 'application/pdf')`.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved my issue by employing a storage.py file that overwrites files with the same name; in my case, I am uploading each file, renaming it to a uniform name, and then having the storage file overwrite it later on rather than Django adding an extension to a file name with the same title.